# What is the name of this Hungarian animation?

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

- **Media:** Movie
- **Date of release/watch:** I watched it a couple of years ago, but the movie itself came out a long time ago (definitely pre-2000)
- **Plot summary:** A mother (in the form of a horse) tells her child a story and thereby narrates most of the movie by describing events and telling stories. It starts by her telling a story about a king dying and the line of succession (two or three brothers fight to get the throne).
- **Setting:** The movie doesn't really have a traditional setting, and this is due to a peculiar way of storytelling (see **Additional info** below)
- **Additional info:** It's a very psychedelic animation, with a black background and bright primary colours. The characters are merely coloured shapes, and they will go from humanoid-shaped to horse-shaped on a whim, with a lot of explosions of colours and flashes. The sound design is also quite psychedelic. Another detail is that once or twice near the beginning, the mother telling the story quite sternly hushes her child. I know it's available on Youtube, too.
- **Country:** Hungary (produced and language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **You are looking for:** [*Son of the White Mare* (1981)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083931/)

**Original title:** *Fehérlófia*

[image: Poster art for the 1981 Hungarian animated motion picture Son of the White Mare, directed by Marcell Jankovics for the Pannónia Filmmstúdió. The poster art was designed by Jankovics himself.]

> Son of the White Mare (Hungarian: Fehérlófia) is a 1981 **Hungarian animated adventure film** directed by Marcell Jankovics.
>   <sub>—[*Son of the White Mare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_the_White_Mare), Wikipedia</sub>
>   Fehérlófia (Son of the White Mare) is **born** as the third son of **a horse**, and he gains his power by suckling the horse's milk. **He listens to old tales**, mostly about the Forefather and the end of his reign, caused by evil dragons.
>   <sub>—[Synopsis (*Son of the White Mare*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Son_of_the_White_Mare#Synopsis), Wikipedia</sub>
>   *Fehérlófia* is a breathtaking piece of animation. Jankovics uses a color scheme of **audaciously bold and vibrant colors** mixed with glowing pastels. The result is a dreamy kaleidoscope of entrancing hues. The style is fluid, as **shapes unfurl seamlessly into other shapes**. The frames are symmetrical, **psychedelic** visions of ancient memory with all of stylistic innovations of the last century.
>   <sub>—[Fehérlófia : The Most Beautiful Psychedelic Trip You’ve Ever Seen](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/network-awesome/feherlofia_b_1326344.html),
>    HuffPost</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I know that you said it is a pre 2000 movie, but I feel like I should just present this finding and make sure with you that it is not it.

How about [Symphony N. 42](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3203054/?ref_=adv_li_tt) (2014)?

> The film presents 47 observations in the irrational connections between human and nature. The film applies an unconventional narrative. It presents a subjective world through 47 scenes. Small events, interlaced by associations, express the irrational coherence of our surroundings. The surreal situations are based on the interactions of humans and nature. Differences between human and animal diminish, everyone is doing their jobs and leaving traces. Every small movement affects another, building an unpredictable, irrational system.

It looks abstract as you described with vibrant colors and shapes becoming humans and animals. Plus, it is Hungarian. Unfortunately I could not find a horse yet, but the word "horse" is between the keywords.

[image]

Comment: The answer to the question comes up in Google if you type `Hungarian animation horse`, but I'm a tad busy to type it out as a fleshed out answer, at the minute.

Comment: @GhotiandChips Oh... Wow... Fehérlófia. I found that movie between the movies where I found this one. But I couldn't make sense of it. Well, answer It whenever you will. :)